# Change background of a specific line of JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

Is there any way to change the background of a specific line of `JTextArea`?

Comment: I see this post, but I would like to change the color of the entire line and not only where there is text (like eclipse editor)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405550/highlight-current-row-in-jtextpane < Check this out. JTextPanes can do cooler stuff anyways. But, they also have their limitations.

Comment: *" Is there any way to change the background of a specific line of `JTextArea`?"*  Select the line.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, how does selecting it help? It only highlights the text, not the entire line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a class that does what I want. Those interested: http://www.camick.com/java/source/LinePainter.java

Thanks.

Comment: Really, what's wrong with a `Highlighter`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, the default HIghlighter doesn't paint the entire line, unless you use the `setDrawsLayeredHighlights(false)` property of the Highlighter. This would probably be the solution for static highlighting. If you want dynamic highlighting based on the caret location you can use the LinePainter.

Comment: @camickr Still scratching my head over the requirements :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, the requirement is to highlight the background of the entire line, not just the background of the text.

Comment: @camickr *"background of a specific line"* - Is open to interruption ;)

Comment: @camickr get the idea, I wanted highlight the background of the entire line. Maybe I didn't express myself very well.